# Placebo Effect Reactions

Tags: immunology

Why do some people actually experience measureable effects when given a placebo(fake drugs) versus the actual drug?  Is is the power of suggestion, belief, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Few examples in which placebo looks effective even if it isn't ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo)):

1. The condition, for example, common cold *heals on its own* in participants who received a real drug and in those who receieved a placebo.
2. In psychological and other conditions in which the participants are asked only how they feel after the treatment, some of them may just *think* that they feel better.
3. Sometimes neither the real drug nor the placebo work, but the condition has a *naturally fluctuating course,* so it looks that they both work.